# Acumatica Report Designer - join on TOP 1

Tags: acumatica

What would be a good way to join on topmost record in acumatica report designer. I'm thinking in terms of DAC views but it is not helping much. So we have two tables and I would like to join on SELECT TOP 1 * from Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an View in sql ("select top 1 ..."), create a DAC for that view, then join in report designer on that sql view.